# Missing Master and Recently Made Branches in Active Repository in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm currently working with a team in vs 2015 while I'm editng my OS got error and suddenly shotdown and when I open the program the master repo and all my branches were lost. I can't find aswers in the internet. please help

[image]

Comment: This sounds like maybe Git is hung on something, causing the VS plugin to show nothing.  Have you tried loading the Git Bash outside VS and typing `git status` or `git branch -a` from your project folder?

Comment: already tried it but still don't find the answer. but thanks for the idea sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by deleting first my local project folder before cloning from vs online. Learned that this is a git error